# Tezos GigaNode snapshots - Quick "latest" URL?

Tags: snapshots

Is there a "latest" URL for https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/?

I mean, if I want to download the latest rolling snapshot, I'd like to retrieve something like https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/latest.rolling

Comment: Ideally, when you import your snapshot, you should know the block hash and should provide the hash during import. This way, you and the import are verifying that the block is correct. This is a safety feature.

Comment: I agree with you, but in case you want to automate a snapshot import for a new node, it'd be easier to just hardcode a "latest" snapshot file and maybe a "latest-blockhash.txt" in order to check the correctness

Answer (score 1):

[xtz-shots.io](https://xtz-shots.io) has "latest snapshot" links.

For example, to download the most recent mainnet rolling snapshot:

```
wget https://mainnet.xtz-shots.io/rolling
```

More details can be found on [XTZ-shots documentation page](https://xtz-shots.io/getting-started/#how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the *xtz-shots.io* answer will suffice for you, but if you really want to use giganode, or want to have a fall-back mechanism to giganode, you can try a simple one liner to extract the latest URL from their webpage.

A rudimentary approach to extract the latest mainnet rolling snapshot:

```
curl -s https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/ | grep "<a href=\"https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/snapshots/mainnet_" | grep rolling | sed -En "s/.*href=\"(.*).rolling\".*/\1\.rolling/p" | head -1
```

As of this writing (27 July 2022) this is the output of that command:

https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/snapshots/mainnet_20220727-135814_BKiVX84KL7pPHfoJRMmCumfJipLbj8iz6vzy3x8EFEitu4A3Rqa.rolling

This is not ideal, as it can easily break if they make any changes to their HTML.